# IIS Not Allowing Connection for Default Site or WCF Service

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I have been trying to implement the Broadcasting Events with a Duplex WCF Service on CodeProject and I can't seem to get IIS to allow a connection. I am using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 8.1 PC. I went into Programs and Features and turned on IIS and it all appeared to come up successfully. The default web site says it's running but I can't seem to load a page from it. I thought it might be a firewall issue but I turned off the fire wall temporarily and nothing changed. I still can't load the simple page that I added to the site and the default IIS page won't come up. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser or Windows Application event log?

Comment: I don't get any error (either from the browser or the event log) when attempting to hit the simple page that I put in the default site. It just comes up with a blank page. When I attempt to hit the WCF service I get an 503 error "Service Unavailable"

Comment: 503 error you will get because of two reasons. 1. Your website where your webapplication resides is stopped or 2. App pool of your webapplication is not started.

Comment: Unfortunately both are running/started. I just went through the pain of completely removing Visual Studio 2013 and IIS and then turned on IIS without installing VS2013. I am getting the same experience. Visual Studio 2010 is installed. Could that have anything to do with this?